# CoreBluetooth iOS if data race possible when using WriteWithoutResponse

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I want to send a byte stream using my peripheral class. So I'm asking myself if the queue is needed for thread safety or if it's safe to delete it to unlock the flow.

I have this following struct

```
private struct WriteWithoutResponseContext {
    let data: Data
    let characteristic: Characteristic
}
```

And this two attributes

```
private var writeWithoutResponseContextQueue = Queue<WriteWithoutResponseContext>()
private let writeWithoutResponseContextCachingDispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "thread-safe-unsent-data-caching", attributes: .concurrent)
```

I'm using the queue with a barrier to make sure everything is blocked until I added it to the queue when canSendWriteWithoutResponse is false.

How do we know that peripheralIsReady is not happening between check of canSendWriteWithoutResponse and enqueueing of context?

```
   func writeValueWithoutResponse(_ data: Data, for characteristic: Characteristic) {
        if self.cbPeripheral.canSendWriteWithoutResponse {
            self.cbPeripheral.writeValue(data, for: characteristic, type: .withoutResponse)
        } else {
            self.writeWithoutResponseContextCachingDispatchQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
                let context = WriteWithoutResponseContext(data: data, characteristic: characteristic)
                self.writeWithoutResponseContextQueue.enqueue(context)
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheralIsReady(toSendWriteWithoutResponse peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        self.writeWithoutResponseContextCachingDispatchQueue.sync {
            if let unsentContext = self.writeWithoutResponseContextQueue.dequeue() {
                self.cbPeripheral.writeValue(unsentContext.data, for: unsentContext.characteristic, type: .withoutResponse)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be safe you need to specify the Queue your `CentralManger` is operating on e.g where your central manager dispatches central role events.
If you not specifying anything the CentralManager will use the main queue which.

```
self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: options)
```

So in my case just creating the CentralManager with a serial queue is fine.

```
let serialQueue =  DispatchQueue(label: "com.Stackoverflow.64819549", qos: .userInitiated)
self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: serialQueue, options: options)
```

With that I don't need the barrier anymore.

Comment: canSendWriteWithoutResponse became false after 10 - 15 mins successfully data sent.  We are still on foreground mode and it's still happening so do you have any hints for us?

Comment: it starts working again if restart the app.